# How to set prefix in string in join?

Tags: c#

I have this strings:

```
string[] codes = new string[]{"66000110", "66000001", "66000121"};
```

I want to make join on strings above:

```
string filter = string.Join(" OR " + some_ID + "=", codes );
```

The resukt I get is:

```
  some_ID=66000110 OR some_ID=66000001 OR some_ID=66000121
```

While I need the string like that(OR missing on start string):

```
      OR some_ID=66000110 OR some_ID=66000001 OR some_ID=66000121
```

How do I fix elegantic way  to get OR on start of the string?

Comment: I think you are overthinking this way too much

Comment: FYI - The result that you SHOULD get is `66000110 OR some_ID=66000001 OR some_ID=66000121`. There is no way the Join() produces what you say it produces. Please be accurate in phrasing your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of LINQ and Concat():

```
string filter = string.Concat(codes.Select(c => " OR " + some_ID + "=" + c));
```

Comment: how about `string.Concat()`

Comment: @ why should I use concat?

Comment: Join with *empty* delimiter - `string.Join("", ...)` can be rewritten as `string.Concat(...)`

Comment:  (Loudly Crying Face) on your code... You don't have any fault in your code, and it is probably more or less what I would write. Still the problem is that if the "correct" way to compose `string`s should be `StringBuilder` (and it is lesson 1 on `string` handling), then there is a problem in your code... But there is no solution in `StringBuilder`, because the `StringBuilder` class is weak in its method. So you have to write "bad" code because there is no way to write "good" code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are building some kind of *SQL*; if it's your case, try switching to `IN`:

```
string filter = $" OR {some_ID} IN ({string.Join(", ", codes)})";
```

And you'll get a more readable equivalent

```
" OR some_ID IN (66000110, 66000001, 66000121)"
```

Comment: I upvoted, but still I want to throw up... Sadly `IN` and `SqlParameter`/`DbParameter` don't mix well... But you shouldn't ever compose a SQL query with `string`s...

Comment: @xanatos: I'd rather said "we seldom compose SQL in such a way and should do it with *care*". If query is temporary one (say, I'm debugging/testing data) and the array is of arbitrary length (it can contain, say, `3` or `33` items) I think it's a possible way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like this?

```
string filter = " or " + string.Join(" OR " + some_ID + "=", codes );
```

Comment: That is what I did in first place. I try to think about more elegantic way :)